# Flutter: Change Textfield if String-Variable is changed from other method

Tags: dart, flutter, uitextfield

The TextField should be changed, if the String - Variable is changed from some other method.

The text box should therefore receive an update if the user enters a new text or the associated variable has been changed from another location.

```
//Calling new text boxes
new eingabeTextbox(false, "Bemerkungen", "...", (String str){zahlerBemerkungen = str; print("neuer Bemerkungswert:" + str);},zahlerBemerkungen),

//paged class to avoid source code redundancy
class eingabeTextbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool _nummerischeTastatur;
  final String _ueberschrift;
  final String _platzhalter;
  ValueChanged<String> eingegebenerWert;
  ValueChanged<String> variableUeberwachen;

  eingabeTextbox(this._nummerischeTastatur, this._ueberschrift, this._platzhalter, this.eingegebenerWert, this.variableUeberwachen);

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return new TextField(
        keyboardType: _nummerischeTastatur == true ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            labelText: _ueberschrift,
            hintText: _platzhalter
        ),
        onSubmitted: eingegebenerWert,
        onChanged: variableUeberwachen
    );
  }
}
```

My approach with "ValueChanged variableUeberwachen;" does not work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to use `TextEditingController` - if you want to change `TextField` value. `onChanged` is function triggered when `TextField` value is changed. Not in reverse as you are trying to do.

Comment: When ever you are trying to change widget in flutter when something else happened elsewhere its mean that you need to use `extends StatefulWidget` and not `extends StatelessWidget`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store the text value, you can listen for text value change using Streams. Here's a sample demonstrating how Streams can be listened to and update the TextField widget when the value from a different widget has been changed.

The `TextField` value can be changed by updating the text value of the `TextEditingController` configured to the Widget.

```dart
StreamBuilder<String?>(
  stream: textEditStream.showText,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
    String? text = snapshot.hasData &&  snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data! : 'Empty';
    // Update value when text has been changed
    textEditingController.text = text;
    return TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
    );
  }
),
```

The StreamListener can be used across screens so it could possibly fit your use case.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleStreamText extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleStreamText({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<SampleStreamText> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<SampleStreamText> {
  final textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: StreamBuilder<String?>(
                stream: textEditStream.showText,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
                  String? text = snapshot.hasData &&  snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data! : 'Empty';
                  // Update value when text has been changed
                  textEditingController.text = text;
                  return TextField(
                    controller: textEditingController,
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter Text Here'),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  textEditStream.setTextEdit(value);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    textEditStream.disposeTextEdit();
  }
}

final textEditStream = TextEdit();

class TextEdit {
  final _text = StreamController<String?>.broadcast();
  Stream<String?> get showText => _text.stream;

  setTextEdit(String? text) {
    debugPrint('Stream sink: $text');
    _text.sink.add(text);
  }

  disposeTextEdit() {
    _text.close();
  }
}
```

Here how it looks like running

[image: Demo]